# CakePHP 1.3: How to prevent a find operation from returning [0] arrays - Recursive Does not work

Tags: arrays, cakephp, recursive-query

I am trying to understand why CakePHP returns arrays like the following even when `recursive=-1` and if there is a way to stop this from happening?

```
array
(
    [0] => array
        (
            [User] => array
                (
                    ... etc...
                )
        )
)
```

Thanks,

Comment: is this from find(all)? what query could did you run?

Comment: Your question is unclear. This is the standard `find('all')` format --a numeric array of: `model alias => model fields`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive -1, reads the model without any relation.

Now brings this Array, because you do a "find (all)", you should do a "find (first)".